# clear <input> tag value when opening new page from search bar

Tags: reactjs

So I have 2 components. SearchBar.js and ProductDetail.js

The searchBar JS help me to search product from my header. And when clicked it will redirect to another productDetail page. the problem is I got  that take a number as the value, when I change it's number and then proceed to search another product. When I got redirected to that productPage, the input value will stay and not reset. How to fix this ?

Here's my code :
ProductDetail.js

```
  const [productCount, setproductCount] = useState(0);

                  <input 
                    type="number" 
                    className='input-quantity' 
                    value={productCount || 1} 
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setproductCount(parseInt(e.target.value))
                    }}
                  />
```

SearchBar.js

```
<div className="searchInput">
  <input
    id="searchKeyInputId"
    type="text"
    placeholder={placeholder}
    onChange={handleFilter}
    ref={inputRef}
  />
  <BiSearch className="input-append-icon" />

  {filteredData.length !== 0 && (
    <div className="searchResult">
      {filteredData && filteredData.slice(0, 5).map((value) => {
        return <Link
          to={`/p/${value.id}/${value.slug}`}
          className="searchItem"
          key={value.id}
          onClick={clearInput}
        >
          <p className='fontRegular'>{value.name}</p>
        </Link>
      })}
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use redux or context. and other way is clear productCount state when user clicked on Link.

Comment: can you provide the parent component's code? it might explain something